# How to create trigger update fields based on other table in django models

Tags: python, django

I have two models, In activity model status is column name this column row has to update from 'Pending' to 'Done', when status column row update from 'Pending' to 'Done' in Item model.It has to update automatically when db field get change.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
   a_id = models.AutoField(primary=True, unique=True)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True,null=True, default="Pending")
class Item(models.Model):
   item_id = models.AutoField(primary=True, uniue=True)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True, default="Pending")
   activityid = models.ForeginKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                           related_name="activitynt")
```

Answer (score 0):

In models.py use signals to update your status

###### models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Activity)
def update_item_status(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    Item.objects.filter(activityid=instance.pk).update(status=instance.status)
```

Comment: I need update automatically when database updated